# Unknown provider when testing service in AngularJS with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've stripped down the app so only the important things are here. I created a service called databaseSrvc and tried to inject in a Jasmine unit test. I've checked a lot of times to see if it was a spelling error, as the [error page suggests](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseObjectProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseObject%20%3C-%20databaseSrvc), so I'm quite sure it's not.

#### Project structure

`.
├── app
│   ├── app.js
│   └── services
│       ├── database.service.js
│       └── database.specs.js
├── lib
│   └── jasmine
│       ├── jasmine-standalone-2.5.2.zip
│       ├── lib
│       ├── MIT.LICENSE
│       ├── spec
│       ├── SpecRunner.html
│       └── src
└── specRunner.html`

#### app.js

`angular.module("firebaseTestApp", [])`

#### database.service.js

```
angular.module("firebaseTestApp")                                                             
    .factory("databaseSrvc", function($firebaseObject) {                                      
        var databaseSrvc = {};                                                                

        databaseSrvc.ref = firebase.database.ref();                                           

        databaseSrvc.echo = function(text) {                                                  
            console.log(test);                                                                
        }                                                                                     

        databaseSrvc.addUser = function(uid, username, email) {                               
            databaseSrvc.ref.child("users").child("uid").set({                                
                username: username,                                                           
                email: email                                                                  
            });                                                                               
        }                                                                                     

        databaseSrvc.removeUser = function(uid, username, email) {                            
            databaseSrvc.ref.child("users").child("uid").removeValue();                       
        }                                                                                     

        databaseSrvc.usernameExists = function(username) {                                    
            query = databaseSrvc.ref.child("user").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
            obj = $firebaseObject(query);                                                     

            return obj.$loaded().then(function() {                                            
                if (obj.$value === null) {                                                    
                    return false;                                                             
                } else {                                                                      
                    return true;                                                              
                }                                                                             
            });                                                                               
        }                                                                                     

        return databaseSrvc;                                                                  
    });
```

#### database.specs.js

Neither the commented part nor the one after it works. It always logs "undefined" and gives me the error mentioned above.

```
describe('databaseSrvc', function() {                              
    beforeEach(module('firebaseTestApp'));

//  var databaseSrvc;                                 
//  beforeEach(inject(function(_databaseSrvc_) {      
//      databaseSrvc = _databaseSrvc_;                
//  }));
//
//                                                      
//  it('should exist', function() {
//      console.log(databaseSrvc);                    
//      expect(databaseSrvc).toBeTruthy();            
//  });                                           

    it('should exist', inject(function(databaseSrvc) {
        console.log(databaseSrvc);                    
        expect(databaseSrvc).toBeTruthy();            
    }));                                              

});
```

#### specRunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                       
<html>                                                                                                
<head>                                                                                                
  <meta charset="utf-8">                                                                              
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.5.2</title>                                                           

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.css">                            

  <script src="lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>                                    
  <script src="lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>                               
  <script src="lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.5.2/boot.js"></script>                                       

  <!-- include source files here... -->                                                               
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>        
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>       

  <script src="app/app.js"></script>                                                                  
  <script src="app/services/database.service.js"></script>                                            

  <!-- include spec files here... -->                                                                 
  <script src="app/services/database.specs.js"></script>                                              

</head>                                                                                               

<body>                                                                                                
</body>                                                                                               
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('databaseSrvc', function() {                              
  beforeEach(module('firebaseTestApp'))
  // declaring in outer scope, will be reassigned below
  var databaseSrvc = {}

  var mockFirebaseObject = function() {
    // this looks like the mock you need based on your service code
    return {
      $loaded: function() {
        return {
          then: function(cb) { cb() }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // provide your mock object as the $firebaseObject
  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$firebaseObject', mockFirebaseObject)
  }))

  // inject the real databaseSrvc factory and reassign it
  // to the variable in your outer scope, so that you can
  // use it in the rest of the specs
  beforeEach(inject(function(_databaseSrvc_) {
    databaseSrvc = _databaseSrvc_
  }))

  describe('expectation', function() {
    it('should do something', function() {
      expect(databaseSrvc)....
    })
  })
})
```

You need to expose the injected service within a scope that the expectations can access.

Comment: I've gone with the second option. I used `inject(function(databaseSrvc, $firebaseObject)`, but still the same thing occurs. Shoul I edit the question with the updated version of them?

Comment: @dr_ate I edited the original answer with an updated spec